# Yup schema - `when` method is not working

Tags: reactjs, schema, yup, react-hook-form

Recently I am suffering with creating yup schema. Since I am doing it I see that the method `when()` totally doesn't work for me like it should as documentation said and other solutions I found on the internet.
When my checkbox is checked to `true` all the fields on the schema should be `required`, but they don't. As seen in my example I tried three ways, and none of them is working. Maybe there is someone who knows what am I doing wrong?

My test code is:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import * as yup from "yup";
import { FormProvider, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { yupResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/yup";
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const schema = yup.object({
    isRequired: yup.bool(),
    firstName: yup.string().when("isRequired", (_, schema) => {
      return schema.required();
    }),
    lastName: yup.string().when("isRequired", () => {
      return yup.string().required();
    }),
    contact: yup.string().when("isRequired", {
      is: true,
      then: yup.string().required("Required")
    })
  });

  const methods = useForm({
    mode: "all",
    defaultValues: {
      isRequired: true,
      firstName: "",
      lastName: "",
      contact: ""
    },
    resolver: yupResolver(schema),
    shouldUnregister: true
  });

  const { register, watch } = methods;
  const isRequired = watch("isRequired");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(schema.fields);
  }, [isRequired, schema]);

  return (
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
      <form autoComplete="off" noValidate>
        <input type="checkbox" {...register("isRequired")} />
        <input {...register("firstName")} />
        <input {...register("lastName")} />
        <input {...register("contact")} />
      </form>
    </FormProvider>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/infallible-wildflower-dsyon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You third solution of how to use `when` was correct. The reason why it wasn't working is that in your first two `when` statements for `firstName` and `lastName` you always return yups `required` method without checking if `isRequired` is `true`.

```js
const schema = yup.object({
  isRequired: yup.bool(),
  firstName: yup.string().when("isRequired", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required()
  }),
  lastName: yup.string().when("isRequired", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required()
  }),
  contact: yup.string().when("isRequired", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required("Required")
  })
});
```

[image: Edit xenodochial-snowflake-eo9f5]

And here is how it would be done when passing a function to `when`.

```
const schema = yup.object({
  isRequired: yup.bool(),
  firstName: yup
    .string()
    .when("isRequired", (isRequired, schema) =>
      isRequired ? yup.string().required() : schema
    ),
  lastName: yup
    .string()
    .when("isRequired", (isRequired, schema) =>
      isRequired ? yup.string().required() : schema
    ),
  contact: yup
    .string()
    .when("isRequired", (isRequired, schema) =>
      isRequired ? yup.string().required() : schema
    )
});
```

[image: Edit practical-pond-49vc4]

Comment: Thank you so much! Now I see that I was too confused on finding solution for my case that I do not check if the validation pass. I was looking all the time for the `exclusiveTests` field on schema and I still do not understand why there is not always information about assigned rules. Do you know something about it?

Comment: I'm not sure i understand your question correctly - what do you mean with _I was looking all the time for the exclusiveTests field on schema and I still do not understand why there is not always information about assigned rules_? Can you please give an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Sorry, I will try to specify. So if you check code on https://codesandbox.io/embed/busy-williams-bktqu and check the schema from console.log, you will see for `firstName` and `lastName` object both has field named `exclusiveTests` - and now when the schema is always .required for `firstName` and conditionally .required for `lastName` the exclusiveTest is `required: true` for `firstName` and empty for `lastName` even if both after submit is required. Should I explain it another way or is it clear that way? Thank you so much for helping :)

Comment: Or maybe there is another way how can I check what validations rules has specific field other than `exclusiveFields` in JS?

Comment: Ok, it seems there is no way to access the list of validations after you defined them via the schema, at least i couldn't find anything related to this. Can you please give an example why you need this information? Maybe there is an easier way how to solve it.

Comment: Thank you so much for everything! :) I was able to somehow workaround my needs, as I use `when` for validation and additionally just check values from form to set inputs label informations conditionally. Really appreciate your help.